# Outputing a Microphone input to a USB Audio output?

Tags: windows-xp, microphone

Say I have some beast USB speakers. I also have a Microphone input on the back of my PC.

The Microphone input will happily output on the same card, but I cannot figure out how to 'route' the output from the Microphone to my USB speakers.

Any help?

Comment: `module-loopback`. No, wait, never mind.

Comment: Yeah, this would have been too easy on Linux :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a piece of software called 'Virtual Audio Cable' to set this up.